# Change the colors of a scatterplot3d trough plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

So, I have 4 columns and I assigned the first 3 to the x,y,z labels of a scatterplot3d in plotly python. My 4 colunm is an array of 1 and 0 and I wanted to set the color of my scatterplot 3D acoording to my 4 column. I also managed that, however, I wanted that it gives me 3 different colors (the third color is related to the points that have the same x,y,z coordinates). Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looking at this:
[3 d scatter plots in plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/)

The second example seems to be relevant. Change "color = z" to your 4th column

```
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        color=z,                # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Viridis',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=0.8
    )
)
```

Comment: Thks! I already have tried it, but that way the points with the same x y and z coordinates aren't highlighted in a diferent color...

Comment: So you want duplicate points to be a different color? I'd isolate those points and do a trace1 / trace2 thing and make sure the opacity is such and the color selection is such that those points stand out.

Comment: what colors would you sugest that can highlight those points ?

Comment: I would personally probably make the opacity on all points 0.50 and the opacity on the highlighted points 1.0, and color would be personal preference. Blue/Blue is probably what I'd do, or Gray/Blue.

Comment: That's a good ideia! However, with the trace 1 / trace2 I can only set the opacity to those 2 traces and not specifically chose the opacity = 1.0 in the duplicated points

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that trace1 is all the points and trace2 is the points you've isolated elsewhere as being the duplicates. i.e., you identify them outside of the actual plotting and trace2 is where you plot those points.